# Python Rock Paper Scissors List Choices

Tags: python, list

Instructions: Write a program to allow the user to play Rock, Paper, Scissors against the computer. The program will be menu driven (see details below). The user can continue to play the game over and over by choosing to play the game in the menu. A game consists of a single battle: win, lose, or tie. For a single battle the user makes their move and then the computer move is displayed followed by a description of who won that battle. Do not break a tie.
Once the user chooses to quit, the program then displays the win/loss/tie record for all the games just played
The user will enter the details in the following order during gameplay:

Menu choice (1 integer, 1 to play a game, 2 to quit)
Player's move (1 string, 'Rock', 'Paper', or 'Scissors')

**My problem is that I'm not sure how to make the computer choose from my list and accept it. I keep getting this...**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRJei.png)

```
import random
def main():
  """
  Runs a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors. Asks the user for input and plays against the computer. 
  """
  
  #print display message
  print('Lets play Rock, Paper, Scissors!')
  
  moves_list = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
  #a place to keep track of scores
  tied = 0
  computer = 0
  player = 0

  #create a variable to control loop 
  play_again = 1 

  comp_choice = process_comp()
  player_choice = process_player()
  winner = determine_winner(player_choice, comp_choice)

  #while loop for multiple games 
  while play_again == 1:
    comp_choice = process_comp()
    player_choice = process_player()
    if comp_choice == 'Rock' or comp_choice == 'rock':
      print('Computer chooses rock.')

    elif comp_choice == 'Paper' or comp_choice == 'paper':
      print('Computer chooses paper.')

    else:
      print('Computer chooses scissors.')

    #call the determine winner function    
    winner = determine_winner(player_choice, comp_choice)

    #check who won the game and add 1 to the correct winner 
    if winner == 'computer':
      computer += 1

    elif winner == 'player':
      player += 1

    else:
      tied += 1
    
    #ask user if they want to play again 
    play_again = input('Would you like to play again? (Enter 1 for yes, 2 for no): ')

    #display number of games that were won
    print()
    print('There were', tied, 'tied games.')
    print('The player won', player, 'games.')
    print('The computer won', computer,'games.')

#define the computer process function 
def process_comp():
  #make computer choose a move from list 
  choosen = random.choice(moves_list)
  return choosen

#make sure user enters correct option. 
def process_player():
  player_choice = int(input('Rock, Paper, Scissors? (Enter 2 if you want to quit):'))
  
  #if the player enters 2, quit the game   
  if player_choice == 2:
    print('Thank you for playing!')
  play_again = 2
  
  #check if user is inputting correct selections 
  while player_choice != 'Rock' or player_choice != 'rock' and player_choice != 'Paper' or player_choice != 'paper' and player_choice != 'Scissors' or player_choice != 'scissors' and player_choice != 2:
    print('Error! Please enter an option that was given.')
    player_choice = int(input('Rock, Paper, Scissors? (Enter 2 if you want to quit):'))
  return player_choice

#define the determine winner function. 
def determine_winner(player_choice, comp_choice):
  
  #setup computer selections 
  if comp_choice == 'Rock' or comp_choice == 'rock':
    if player_choice == 'Paper' or player_choice == 'paper':
      print('You win!')
      winner = 'player'

    elif player_choice == 'Scissors' or player_choice == 'scissors':
      print('The computer wins!')
      winner = 'computer'

    else:
      print('The game is tied. Try again.')
      winner = 'tied'

  if comp_choice == 'Paper' or comp_choice == 'paper':
    if player_choice == 'Rock' or player_choice == 'rock':
      print('The computer wins!')
      winner = 'computer'

    elif player_choice == 'Scissors' or player_choice == 'scissors':
      print('You win!')
      winner = 'player'

    else:
      print('The game is tied. Try again.')
      winner = 'tied'

  if comp_choice == 'Scissors' or comp_choice == 'scissors':
    if player_choice == 'Rock' or player_choice == 'rock':
      print('You win!')
      winner = 'player'

    elif player_choice == 'Paper' or player_choice == 'player':
      print('The computer wins!')
      winner = 'computer'

    else:
      print('The game is tied. Try again.')
      winner = 'tied'

  return winner

main()
```

Comment: If you input `rock`, how do you expect Python to translate that to an integer? :)

Comment: `moves_list` is a local variable in `main()` you can't access it from `process_comp()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to translate a string, e.g. `rock` into an integer (number). This is not possible as Python has no way of knowing the integer you wish to translate it into. Instead you could change your `process_player()` to the following. I simplified your while statement, and removed the translation to `int` - Then you check for whether `player_choice` is equal to the string `'2'` instead of the integer version, and it should work

```py
    def process_player():
        player_choice = input('Rock, Paper, Scissors? (Enter 2 if you want to quit):')

        # if the player enters 2, quit the game   
        if player_choice == '2':
            print('Thank you for playing!')

        # check if user is inputting correct selections 
        while player_choice.lower() not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', '2']:
            print('Error! Please enter an option that was given.')
            player_choice = input('Rock, Paper, Scissors? (Enter 2 if you want to quit):')
        return player_choice
```